# Difficulty when constructing a nested data structure

Tags: data-structures, raku

While trying to create a JSON message for an API, I found myself struggling to do something that I thought would be simple. I needed to create a message like the following:

```
{ "list": [ { "foo": 1, "bar": 2 } ] }
```

However, my first attempt did not work:

```
say to-json { foo => [ { a => 1, b => 2 } ] };
# {"foo":[{"a":1},{"b":2}]}
```

Trying to simplify things further confused me more:

```
say { foo => [ { a => 1 } ] };
# {foo => [a => 1]}
# Note that this is not JSON, but I expected to see curly braces
```

Then I tried to use some temporary variables, and that worked:

```
my @list = { a => 1 };
say to-json { foo => @list };
# {"foo":[{"a":1}]}

my %hash = ( a => 1 );
say to-json { foo => [ %hash ] };
# {"foo":[{"a":1}]}
```

What's going on here?

And is there a way I can achieve my desired output without an extra temporary variable?

Comment: `say to-json { foo => [ { a => 1 } ] };` should output something like `{"foo":[{"a":1}]}`, not `{"foo":["a":1]}`. The latter is a typo, right? If not, what does `say $*PERL.compiler.version;` say?

Comment: Hm, yeah, you're right. I guess I misread things when I was trying stuff out. Even `say to-json { foo => [ a => 1 ] }` outputs `{"foo":[{"a":1}]}` so who knows what I typed when I got that, if I ever did. My bad!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You've discovered the [single argument rule](https://docs.perl6.org/syntax/Single%20Argument%20Rule). Numerous constructs in Raku will iterate the argument they are provided with. This includes the `[...]` array composer. This is why when we say:

```
say [1..10];
```

We get an array that contains 10 elements, not 1. However, it also means that:

```
say [[1,2]];
```

Iterates the `[1,2]`, and thus results in `[1,2]` - as if the inner array were not there. A `Hash` iterates to its pairs, thus:

```
{ foo => [ { a => 1, b => 2 } ] }
```

Actually produces:

```
{ foo => [ a => 1, b => 2 ] }
```

That is, the array has the pairs. The JSON serializer then serializes each pair as a one-element object.

The solution is to produce a single-element iterable. The infix `,` operator is what produces lists, so we can use that:

```
say to-json { foo => [ { a => 1, b => 2 }, ] };
#                        note the , here ^
```

Then the single argument to be iterated is a 1-element list with a hash, and you get the result you want.

Easy way to remember it: always use trailing commas when specifying the values of a list, array or hash, even with a single element list, unless you actually are specifying the single iterable from which to populate it.

Comment: The other way is to itemize in a Scalar: { foo => [ ${ a => 1, b => 2 } ] }